# Unable to run browse-kill-ring

Tags: debugging, font-lock, kill-ring

After installing the `browse-kill-ring` package under Emacs 24.5.1, I get the following error when running the `browse-kill-ring` command:

> font-lock-set-defaults: Wrong type argument: symbolp, (font-lock-fontify-region-function . browse-kill-ring-fontify-region)

What is going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, consider reporting a bug to the library maintainer. If not, recursively bisect your init file until you find the culprit.

FWIW, I see no such problem, using Emacs 24.5.

Comment: Yes, I still see the same problem after only `(package-initialize)` and `(require 'browse-kill-ring)`. However, others don't seem to observe this...

Comment: The latest commit by the developer approximately 21 hours ago appears to discuss this same topic -- perhaps the bug was just introduced recently by the developer: https://github.com/browse-kill-ring/browse-kill-ring  Here is a link to the commit: https://github.com/browse-kill-ring/browse-kill-ring/commit/b36d5a9e0f7dbf9cad147e52067e3bfe757cd271  There may be additional related commit history -- I have not looked at each commit prior to the most recent commit.

Comment: @lawlist Maybe, that issue is already solved in the git repository: https://github.com/browse-kill-ring/browse-kill-ring/issues/62